# Getting value only from Node.js MySQL result object

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to get a list of distinct values from a MySQL Column and return these in a single JSON array.

I have this current code:

```js
app.get('/experiences/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', http://localhost:3000');
    connection.query('SELECT DISTINCT experience FROM questions', function(err, data) {
        err ? res.send(err) : res.json(data);
    });
});
```

I want the result to look like:

```
{experience: ["1-3","1-5","5+"]}
```

but it currently looks like:

```
[{"experience":"1-3"},{"experience":"1-5"},{"experience":"5+"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reformat the data object you get by looping on the array and recreate an object with the correct format.
Like this :

```
connection.query('SELECT DISTINCT experience FROM questions', function(err, data) {
    if(err)
        res.send(err)
    else {
        let experiences = [];
        data.forEach(function(
            experiences.push(d.experience);
        }
        result = {experience : experiences };
        res.json(result);
    }
});
```